# Monitor OpenShift Cluster and Applications using Managed Service for Prometheus

Tags: google-cloud-platform, openshift, google-cloud-monitoring, openshift-4, google-managed-prometheus

We have OpenShift cluster running on GCE instances which hosts various Applications and Middleware components i.e. Elasticsearch, Kafka, keyCloak, Micro Services (Java and Python based) and Camunda.

We are exploring GCP Managed Service for Prometheus as one stop monitoring solution for infra, Middleware and Application metrics . As GCP natively supports Application Exporters for Elastic Search and Kafka.

I would like to understand if we can use these application exporters in the OpenShift Cluster after enabling Managed collection for non-GKE Kubernetes environment.

Documentation says below as part of  Prerequisites for Elasticsearch and Kafka Application exporters :

*Your cluster must be running Google Kubernetes Engine version 1.21.4-gke.300 or later.*

GCP Exporter References:

https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/exporters/kafka
https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/exporters/elasticsearch

Please let me know if anyone has tried these GCP native exporters for Elasticsearch and Kafka in non GKE environment.

Thanks,

Raj